# In which language/script this code is?

Tags: javascript, cakephp

I am customising one cakephp plugin for my website.
in that there is some code written in `<% %>`  tags.
Is this javascript?I am unable to write functions in this.
How to modify it?

> Edited

This is the sample code

```
<%
var count = 0;
var data;
for(var validdata in data){
count++;
}
%>
```

I want to write function in it.And this is index.ctp file

Comment: Not familiar with cakePHP but can you be more eleborative and show the code written in `<% %>` also what file is it? Is it a templating file?
If so maybe it could be some js logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should see your code, so please post the script.

Anyway, `<%` and `%>` are PHP tags called ASP tags, as you can see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php), even if the official documentation says:

> The ASP tags <%, %>, <%=, and the script tag 
>   are removed from PHP v7.0.0.